# Exception thrown: 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' . How to encrypt and decrypt securestring in dotnet core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core, encryption, .net-core-3.1, securestring

**OS:** Ubuntu

**Platform:** dotnet core 3.1

I was trying to do encryption and decryption of secure string using following method.But getting following exception.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' in System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll: 'Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI) is not supported on this platform.'
```

**Encrption Method**

```
        public static string EncryptString(System.Security.SecureString input)
        {
            byte[] encryptedData = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(
                System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(ToInsecureString(input)),
                entropy,
                System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
        }
```

**Decryption Method**

```
        public static SecureString DecryptString(string encryptedData)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] decryptedData = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(
                    Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedData),
                    entropy,
                    System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
                return ToSecureString(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedData));
            }
            catch
            {
                return new SecureString();
            }
        }
```

How to encrypt and decrypt securestring in dotnet core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sorry but this API is only supported on Windows. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/unsupported-apis